# How do I switch between nav-pills and nav-stacked for different screen sizes?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to figure out how to switch between `nav-stacked nav-pills` for mobile and `non-nav-stacked nav-pills` for everything else using Bootstrap. 
For example, for desktop:

```
 <nav>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

And for mobile:

```
 <nav>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer my own question, in case anybody else is helped by it. I found that a good way is to use the .hidden class. For example in the above code, the first block's class would be modified as such:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills hidden-xs">
```

And the second block's class would be modified as such:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked visible-xs-inline">
```

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the size of the screen that you want the specific menu to show in.
Give the nav an ID.

```
<nav id="desktopNav">
```

and

```
<nav id="mobileNav">
```

This is what I would do.

FOR DESKTOP
I would hide the mobile menu

```
#mobileNav{ display:none;}
```

FOR MOBILE
I would hide the desktop menu

```
#desktopNav{ display:none;}
```

Basically, what this will do, is show the desktopNav when you are looking at it on a computer or maybe tablet, and then show the mobileNav when on a phone.

Within your CSS, you want to do this for mobile devices

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
     ENTER YOUR CSS CODE HERE
}
```

This would go at the end of your CSS file. This tells the brower that any device that is under 600px it will do something else. You would put the desktopNav in there. This is called a responsive website.